# print both value and keys in angular?

Tags: angular

Am just facing a issue **Can't Print Property name** in Angular

```
array = [{name: 'name1', id: 1},{name: 'name2', id: 2}]

<div *ngFor="let name of array">
    <p>Name: {{name.name}}</p> // Hard coded here (Name:)
</div>
```

how to do same without hard coding. 
Am searching for this but everyone suggest to implements this by using Pipe.

Is there alternate or easy way there .? to implement this.

Comment: The access to the property is harcoded too: `{{name.name}}` so why does it bother you so much? Or maybe you want to turn both of them dynamic?

Comment: am asking is there simple syntax like {{name.name}} for property name

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generic function to retrieve an object's key given a value:

```
function getKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(x=> obj[x] === value);
}
```

and use that in your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of array">
    <p>{{getKey(obj , obj.name)}}: {{obj.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use pipe to avoid redundant calculation

Comment: @yurzui yes, that's definitely a valid alternative

Comment: I still don't see the point, as you also actually harcode the property name in the function call `{{getKey(obj , obj.name)}}`, why not just write "Name"? But the OP may know what he's doing..

Answer (score 0):

Using pipe will be the best option i think, why you don't want to use them?, you can use them easily

```
<p *ngFor="let name of array">
    <p *ngFor="let property of name | ObjNgFor">
         {{ property }}: {{ name[property]}} 
    </p>
</p>
```

And pipe will be like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({ name: 'ObjNgFor'})
export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: any): any {
     return Object.keys(value);
     }
}
```